What is minimum Jetty version compatible with Java 17?
I am currently using Azul Zulu OpenJDK version 1.8 and Jetty version 9.4.49 for my project. However, I plan to upgrade my Java version to Azul Zulu OpenJDK 17, which is a long-term support version of the Java Development Kit. I would like to ensure that the Jetty server version I use is fully compatible with Azul Zulu OpenJDK 17.
Could you please suggest a Jetty version that is known to work well with Java 17?
Additionally, it would be helpful if you could provide some insight into any potential changes or considerations I should be aware of when upgrading both Java and Jetty in my project. Are there any specific compatibility issues, configuration updates, or new features in Jetty that I should take advantage of or be cautious about?

tl;dr

Jetty 12 is the only version maintained free-of-cost.
Jetty 12 can directly run your Jetty 9 web app, without modification.
Jetty 12 runs on Java 17 and later.

Jetty 12
Read the fine manual.
To quote:

What Version Do I Use?
Jetty 12 is currently the community-supported version of Jetty.


 So Jetty 12 is the only version to use free-of-cost.
You may choose to purchase commercial support for the older versions from the Webtide company.

Fortunately, Jetty 12 was re-architected to support each of the major generations of the Servlet & JSP technologies. So Jetty 12 subsumes the purpose of Jetty 9, 10, and 11.

Servlet specifications: 3.1, 4.0, 5.0, and 6.0.
Jakarta Pages (formerly JSP) specifications: 2.3, 3.0, and 3.1.

So, good news: You need not modernize your Servlet 3.1 / JSP 2.3 app if that would be uncomfortable. You should be able to move your Jetty 9.4 web app directly to Jetty 12. You will test thoroughly of course, but should expect success.
(I do recommend eventually modernizing to the latest Jakarta EE generation when convenient.)
 Jetty 12 requires Java 17 or later.

I was trying to configure jett-ssl.xml but i am getting this error
2024-11-29 15:02:11.186:WARN :oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Unable to execute XmlConfiguration
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No matching constructor class org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector

@Adam You should post a fleshed-out Question on that topic.

can please answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79237882/jetty-12-unable-to-execute-xmlconfiguration-java-lang-runtimeexception-java-l
