Jetty 12 : Unable to execute XmlConfiguration java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No matching constructor class
So i migrated from jetty 9 to 12.0.15 and now i am trying to configure jetty-ssl.xml where i have ssl.ini in base.
When i try to start the webserver i am getting error
2024-11-29 15:02:11.186: WARN :oejx.XmlConfiguration:main: Unable to execute XmlConfiguration
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No matching constructor class org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.lambda$main$3(XmlConfiguration.java:2000)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:2005)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    

This is my jetty-ssl.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "https://jetty.org/configure_10_0.dtd">


<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

  <!-- Configure SSL context with your keystore and truststore -->
  <New id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory$Server">
    <Set name="keyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath" default="/etc/keystore.p12"/></Set>
    <Set name="keyStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword" default="storepwd"/></Set>
    <Set name="keyManagerPassword"><Property name="jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword"/></Set>
  </New>

  <!-- Create a new ServerConnector for SSL -->
  <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New id="sslSdaConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                <Arg><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
                <Arg>http/1.1</Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory"/>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.ssl.port" default="8443"/></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="jetty.ssl.idleTimeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.ssl.host" default="localhost"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>

</Configure>


I have searched everywhere please suggest some solutions
